# How to sort and group CSV file containing a list of employees by department and title with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sorting, grouping

I'm creating an employee directory CSV file that I generate after querying `Get-ADUser` and I want to customize the sorting and grouping. I am able to sort my CSV file by department, but I want to further group each department with the department heads listed first.

**How can I sort my csv list of employees by department and still group department heads at the top of each department?**

Here is how I am sorting by department.

```
$departments = "Executive|IT|HR|Billing"

$searchQuery = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "mysearchbase" |
               Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $true -and $_.department -ne $null} |
               Select-Object department, name, title, mail, telephonenumber

# Employee list sorted by $departments
$deptSortedObj = $searchQuery |
                 Sort-Object { $departments.IndexOf($_.department) }

foreach ($employee in $deptSortedObj) {
    $employeeList = [Ordered]@{
        department = $employee.department
        name       = $employee.name
        title      = $employee.title
        email      = $employee.mail.ToLower()
        extension  = $employee.telephoneNumber.Split('x')[1]
    }
    $obj += New-Object PSObject -Property $employeeList
}

$obj | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," |
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '"',''} |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Add-Content contact.csv
```

This is an example of my desired output.
*(note, the department heads should be grouped at the top of each department. Department heads are for example: CEO, Billing Manager, VP, Director, Supervisor)*

```
Executive,Jane Doe,CEO,email@example.com,9932
Executive,John Smith,Administrative Assistant,email@example.com,9932
Billing,Tina Dina,Billing Manager,email@example.com,9932
Billing,Bill Dill,Billing Clerk,email@example.com,9932
Billing,Tommy Wommy,Payables,email@example.com,9932
```

My current output is only sorted by department.

Comment: how do you know what the sort order would be for the `.Title` property? ///// purely as an aside, why are you wrecking your CSV? stripping out the headers is ... odd. [*grin*]

Comment: Ideally I would sort based on a list of my own defined titles (e.g. CEO, Manager, Director, etc) like I am doing for $departments. I am using some JavaScript to create a little employee directory website on an intranet, the headers are not necessary

Comment: thank you for the clarification. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) can sort by multiple criteria. If you have a defined list of "head of department" job titles you could sort like this:

```
$titles = 'CEO', 'Manager', 'Director'
$deptSortedObj = $searchQuery |
                 Sort-Object {$departments.IndexOf($_.department)},
                     @{expression={$_.Title -in $titles}; descending=$true}, Name
```